# How to make an image clickable and cursor be a pointer if image is drawn in canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I make an image in canvas using the following code:

```
    Img={};
    Img.pause=new Image();
    Img.pause.src="pause.png";
    //some time later
    ctx.drawImage(Img.pause, 650, 15, 40, 40);
```

How can I check if user is clicking the image? Also, how can I make the mouse a pointer over this image? I've tried:

```
    Img.pause.style.cursor="pointer";
```

but that didn't work. I know I could just make this image with html and target it via its ID, but is there a way to do it with js only?

Comment: Since your image is a rectangle, you can just use math to test if the mouse is inside the image: `if(mouseX > img.x && mouseX < img.x + img.height && mouseY>img.y && mouseY<img.y+img.height`. If true, change the cursor on the canvas element.

Comment: @Nick Solonko Your Image is not being put into the DOM, so there's never a time when the cursor can be above it, so setting the cursor style will do nothing.  drawImage does not manipulate the DOM, it just renders an image onto a canvas.  markE suggestion is one way of doing what you want, but you could also do other things.  If the image is a single color, check if the color under the cursor matches and if so change the cursor